# Config nginx for Vue.js distribute project

Tags: nginx, vue.js

I use the nginx for Vue.js dist server.

my Nginx config is bellow:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  qy.abc.xyz;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/qy.abc.xyz.access.log  main;

    location / {
        access_log /data/nginx_log/access.log main;
        error_log  /data/nginx_log/error.log error;
        root /data/ldl/repo/vue_user_site/dist;
        index  index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }
    ...
```

I can access the `qy.abc.xyz` in browser success, but I can you know in my Vue.js there are many routes, if I access `qy.abc.xyz/index` or `qy.abc.xyz/xxx/xxx`, Nginx will get the `404 Not Found` error.

You know the `dist` directory is constituted by many `hashed-name.js` and a `index.html`.

How to config my Nginx for my project?

---

**EDIT-1**

I tried use this config, but not work.

```
location / {
    access_log /data/nginx_log/access.log main;
    error_log  /data/nginx_log/error.log error; 
    #root /data/ldl/repo/vue_user_site/dist;
    #index  index.html;

    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    return 200 /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to configurate [URL Rewrite](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

you can try this

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|ico)$ {
    root <your static file root>
}
location / {
    return 200 /index.html
    # or use rewrite
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.html
}
```

Or use some server code that has route like `node` , `asp.net core`   to send your html

Comment: do you restart your nginx to reload your config ?

Comment: I have use `nginx -s reload`

Answer (score 0):

Follow my settings of single-page application config in Nginx:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name qy.abc.xyz;

    #access_log /var/log/logs/qy.abc.xyz.access.log  main; 

    charset utf-8;

    index index.html;
    root /data/ldl/repo/vue_user_site/dist;


    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;

    }

    location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```